# xcode 4 build settings precompiled header path disappeared?

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode4

In xcode 3.2.5 you can add extra header paths to your project. I can't find precompiled header path line in xcode 4, where they put that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You use Basic, click All!